# Firebase queryOrderedbyChild doesn't return a Null value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a query that searches for users based on their age:

```
self?.ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "age").queryStarting(atValue: "18").queryEnding(atValue: "25").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with:  { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
```

My Firebase structure is like this:

```
users
    -> uid1
        -> age : "18"
        -> name : "Lisa"
        -> ...
    -> uid2
        -> age : "18"
        -> name : "Elizabeth"
        -> ...
```

In my DB there are two people withe age : "18".

Everything works well when queryStartingAtValue is "18".

The issue occurs when I change the queryStartingAtValue to the non-existing age (e.g. "19").

Indeed, no results are returned, the data seems to be blocked inside the query.

Do you have any idea what's wrong with this query?

Thx.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "blocked inside the query"

Comment: Hi! The query returns no value, not even null. Nothing happens. I tried with .value instead of .childAdded and it returns a null when it doesn't match with  the age. This issue with .childAdded prevents me from checking if snapshot.exists ().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the data you show there are no nodes with `19` or higher, so the query doesn't match any nodes. In that case the `.childAdded` event does not fire.

If you want to detect this condition, you must listen to the `.value` event, which *does* fire even when there are no children. But you'll get a single `.value` event for all matching children in this case, so you'll need to [loop over the child nodes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events):

```
self?.ref.child("users")
  .queryOrdered(byChild: "age").queryStarting(atValue: "18")
  .queryEnding(atValue: "25")
  .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot.exists())
    for child in snapshot.children {
      ...
    }
```