# Retrieving specific data from Firebase realtime database in swift 5.0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not good in **firebase**, but I'm making one project regrading chat app. i have created one not node **GroupChat** inside that i create group with including members. now i want to check that if **userid** is available in subchild node like **UserInfo/userid** . You can get esaily idea by watching below structure . AnyHelp can be appreciate.  [image]

Here is my coding for retrive data for specific value.

```
let questionPostsRef = Database.database().reference().child("GroupChat")
let query = questionPostsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "UserInfo/userid").queryEqual(toValue: FireStoreApp.shared.objUser.strUserID)// Here i pass userid that i want to check in firebase.
 query.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { snapshot in

         print(snapshot.value)
         if !snapshot.exists() { return }
         for child in snapshot.children {
                let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let dict = childSnap.value as! [String: Any]
                print(dict)
         }
 })
```

Thank you in advance for your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
let questionPostsRef = Database.database().reference().child("GroupChat").child("LfY0_k5TakQ1EuPiGQU").child("UserInfo");
let query = questionPostsRef.queryOrdered(byChild:"userid").queryEqual(toValue: FireStoreApp.shared.objUser.strUserID)// Here i pass userid that i want to check in firebase.
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

     print(snapshot.value)
     if !snapshot.exists() { return }
     for child in snapshot.children {
            let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let dict = childSnap.value as! [String: Any]
            print(dict)
     }
})
```

You need to traverse the database from top to bottom, therefore you need to add the child `child("LfY0_k5TakQ1EuPiGQU")` to be able to then check if `userId` exists or not.

Also when you want to check if a child exists you need to use [`.value`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598870/firebase-queryorderedbychild-doesnt-return-a-null-value/44599584#44599584) event instead of `.childadded`.

Comment: but how can i know the value of  LfY0_k5TakQ1EuPiGQU this kind of child i have multiple child node right now.

Comment: when adding values to your database, you can add the `childByAutoID` to a variable and then add the variable in the `child()` method same as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328328/firebase-retrieve-childbyautoid-from-realtime-database.  The other way is to use firebase authnetication and instead of `childByAutoID` you would use the `userID`

Comment: my group id and Childnode id both are same

Comment: but how can i use directly that value i have only groupchat node inside that i made childnotes that single group chat info inside that i have userinfo subchild node and inside that i have userid and i want to check directly that userid without calling another api request for single node

Comment: and my question is Should i check directly userid from groupchat node ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is this code...

```
.queryOrdered(byChild: "UserInfo/userid")
```

doesn't work as UserInfo doesn't have a direct child of userid. It's children are 0, 1, 2 etc

Second thing is; in general it's best to try to avoid arrays in NoSQL databases.

A possible solution is to change your structure to match what you are tryng to do.

instead of

```
GroupChat
   uid
      UserInfo
        0...
        1...
        2...
```

where 0, 1, 2 are unknowns... change it to

```
GroupChat
   uid
      UserInfo
        uid_x
           PhotoUrl
           username
        uid_y
           PhotoUrl
           username     
        uid_z
           PhotoUrl
           username
```

That structure makes it easy to see if a uid already exists in UserInfo as you will know the direct path. It also avoids running a query altogether which saves resources (queries are heavier than direct observers) Here's some pseudo code

```
let pathToCheck = rootRef.child("GroupChat").child(uid).child("UserInfo").child(uid_to_look_for)
```

then

```
pathToCheck.observeSingleEvent.... { snapshot in
  if snapshot.exists() {
     // do something with the snapshot
  } else {
     print("user does not exist in group")
  }
}
```